# How to use TikZ in Lyx

Tags: lyx

How do you use TikZ efficiently in Lyx?
I understand I have to go to Insert->Tex code, which opens a box where I can type actual Tex code. But it's really difficult, there is no indentation, everything I type is in one color only. (Note: I'm using Lyx on Mac)
Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: why no indentation? Tab does not work for you? If you're referring to pasting, make sure you do Edit > Paste Special > Plain Text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write your `tikzpicture` in a separate plain text file, then include it in your LyX document, using the menu item **Insert | File | Child Document**.

You have to make sure that you use the *Include type: Input* here.

[image]

Comment: Isn't there a tikz GUI editor on Lyx?.  Working directly, without importing is very important, specially when dealing with diagrams, you may need to connect some parts of your already made content.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Latex editor and copy paste the code once you're done. Or use a Latex editor, save file and import it to lyx.
lyx is supposed to be a text editor, somewhat like MS word, and indeed using ERT is not fun.

btw, you can use ctrl+L to open the ERT box