# Filling an annulus sector with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the following graphic using tikz:

[image]

Is it possible to draw this without using any packages? I can draw the coordinate system as well as both of the arcs but how do I get the space in between filled and also the connections between the arcs give me trouble.

Comment: Welcome! Without using any packages, are you sure? You have to use at least one package if you use Ti*k*Z. Btw, please add a picture you have drawn so far, so we can have some addition if possible.

Comment: Okay, I will make a picture now and post it. Give me a couple of minutes. I just got an idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must load `tikz` package if you want to use Ti*k*Z :)) So I assume that you don't allow to load any additional packages.

In the following proposals, it seems that I don't use any packages. However, I do load one. `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` already load `tikz`.

---

The angles are drawn with `quotes` and `angles` libraries. They are not packages, so I hope this answer is valid.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=black!20] (140:1) coordinate (beta) arc (140:-70:1) coordinate (alpha) -- (-70:2) arc (-70:140:2) -- cycle;
\draw (-2.5,0)--(2.5,0) coordinate (x);
\draw (0,-2.5)--(0,2.5);
\fill (1,0) circle (1pt) node[below right] {$c^a$} (2,0) circle (1pt) node[below right] {$c^b$};
\coordinate (o) at (0,0);
\pic[draw,<-,"$\alpha$",angle radius=0.4cm,angle eccentricity=1.4] {angle=alpha--o--x};
\pic[draw,->,"$\beta$",angle radius=0.6cm,angle eccentricity=1.3] {angle=x--o--beta};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

However, if you don't want to load a single library, you can play with `arc` and `node[midway]`, although this is a bit more difficult

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=black!20] (140:1) coordinate (beta) arc (140:-70:1) coordinate (alpha) -- (-70:2) arc (-70:140:2) -- cycle;
\draw (-2.5,0)--(2.5,0) coordinate (x);
\draw (0,-2.5)--(0,2.5);
\fill (1,0) circle (1pt) node[below right] {$c^a$} (2,0) circle (1pt) node[below right] {$c^b$};
\coordinate (o) at (0,0);
\draw[->] (0.4,0) arc (0:-70:0.4) node[midway,below right,inner sep=1pt] {$\alpha$};
\draw[->] (0.6,0) arc (0:140:0.6) node[below right,inner sep=0pt] {$\beta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Recommended approach:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=black!20] (140:1) coordinate (beta) arc (140:-70:1) coordinate (alpha) -- (-70:2) arc (-70:140:2) -- cycle;
\draw (-2.5,0)--(2.5,0) coordinate (x);
\draw (0,-2.5)--(0,2.5);
\fill (1,0) circle (1pt) node[below right] {$c^a$} (2,0) circle (1pt) node[below right] {$c^b$};
\coordinate (o) at (0,0);
\pic[draw,<-,"$\alpha$",angle radius=0.4cm,angle eccentricity=1.4] {angle=alpha--o--x};
\pic[draw,->,"$\beta$",angle radius=0.6cm,angle eccentricity=1.3] {angle=x--o--beta};
\draw[very thin,dashed] (alpha)--(o)--(beta);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The reason why I don't want any packages is because I use LyX instead of LaTeX and often face issues with downloading packages and getting them to work. If there is a solution (like your second one) that doesn't require packages I'm glad. So thanks for altering your solution!

Comment: @RedLantern If you don't want to load `tikz`, you have only one option: using the `picture` environment, which is definitely _extremely_ difficult to use.

Comment: @RedLantern There are many questions here about how to use Ti*k*Z in LyX. Take [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/276814/156344), for example.

Comment: @RedLantern Btw I don't think you need to download packages manually. What is your TeX distribution (i.e. MiKTeX or TeX Live or something...)?

Comment: No, don't worry. I already got tikz installed and working. But it took a while and every time I need a new package it requires time and work to get it working so I prefer to know how to draw stuff in tikz with only the basic commands.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with `\filldraw` with some arcs. The use of polar coordinatesd like `(-70:1)` means starting poiunt is at -70 degrees and distance 1 from origin. The `cycle`at the end of the path closes the draw command.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-3,0) -- (3,0);
  \draw (0,-3) -- (0,3);
  \filldraw[fill=gray!30,opacity=0.7] (-70:1) arc (-70:150:1) -- (150:2) arc (150:-70:2) -- cycle;
  \draw[->] (0:0.7) arc (0:-70:0.7)node[pos=0.5,anchor=-35]{$\alpha$};
  \draw[->] (0:0.8) arc (0:150:0.8)node[pos=0.9,anchor=150]{$\beta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. But I'm not sure if I fully understand what you did there. The (-70:1) is the starting point of the arc in polar coordinates? And adding --cycle in the end closes the graph by drawing the connections between the two arcs?

Comment: Yes, I have added that in the description.